# É necessário versionar a pasta node_modules no Git?

Tags: git, módulo-ecmascript

Estou criando um projeto em Angular. Quando fui adicionar o projeto ao Git para fazer o commit, o terminal informou que o `.gitignore` está ignorando a pasta `node_modules`.

Percebi que a pasta tem muitos arquivos, mas é importante e necessário adicioná-la ao Git para que o projeto rode do mesmo jeito em outra máquina ou quem clonar o repositório irá executar isso ao baixar o projeto em sua máquina?

Comment: não deve, nem é necessário, o que você deve adicionar no git é o `package-lock.json`, pois na hora de executar o `npm install` ele irá baixar as versões exatas dos pacotes.

Comment: Essa é uma ótima pergunta na realidade. Acredito que vá ajudar muitos iniciantes :)

Answer (score 2):

Essa é uma dúvida muito comum para pessoas que estão iniciando na área de desenvolvimento e vão mexer com algum framework Javascript.

Só para dar um contexto histórico: Antes do lançamento do Node, geralmente era necessário baixar dependências manualmente e colocá-las no projeto. Cada pluguin, font e biblioteca precisava ser baixada e adicionada em alguma pasta e versionada juntamente com o projeto, senão ele não funcionaria. Se fosse preciso usar uma versão mais recente de uma dependência, isso era feito excluindo os arquivos e então baixando a versão mais nova e colocando no lugar(Imagina o caos as vezes haha). Mais tarde, surgiram algumas soluções pra deixar esse trabalho mais fácil, como o [Bower](https://bower.io/). Mas, o que realmente revolucionou a comunidade de Javascript foi o lançamento do [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/) junto com seu gerenciador de pacotes, o [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/).

Com o node e o npm, ficou muito mais fácil criar e compartilhar código javascript, e com isso surgiram muitas libs para fazer tudo que se possa imaginar. E, além disso as ferramentas de frontend avançaram muito após, ficando com cada vez mais dependências. Mas, diferente do trabalho chato que citei antes de gerenciar manualmente, o npm consegue por meio do `package.json` salvar todas as dependências que seu projeto necessita, e cada dependência consegue baixar as suas próprias dependências e assim por diante. Além disso, agora é possível fazer update ou remoção de dependências de maneira muito mais fácil, com um simples comando.

Depois, foi criado um arquivo chamado `package-lock.json`. Esse arquivo é gerado automaticamente a primeira vez que você instalar as dependências. Como eu comentei, o npm cuida de instalar as dependências listadas no `package.json` e instalar as dependências das dependências, gerando uma espécia de arvore de dependências. Então, antes de existir o lock, algumas vezes alguma dependência podia ter conflito de versão por ser uma dependência do seu projeto em uma versão X e ao mesmo tempo ser uma dependência de outra dependência na versão Y, fazendo com que o projeto não funcionasse. Então, o `package-lock.json` serve para salvar exatamente a árvore de dependências e evitar que esse tipo de conflito aconteça.

Agora que expliquei o papel do npm e seu `package.json` e do `package-lock.json`, acho que deu para perceber que os arquivos de dependência em si não precisam ser versionados, porque o npm cuidará disso para você. Se olhar atentamente para o conteúdo da pasta node_modules, verá que é gigantesco e facilmente pode chegar até 1gb ou mais de tamanho. Seria bem improdutivo salvar todos esses arquivos desnecessariamente, já que o npm cuida exatamente de podermos baixar todos eles, na versão correta com apenas um comando.

Então, quando vamos versionar um projeto no git, seja de Frontend ou de Node, nós precisamos apenas salvar os arquivos do nosso projeto e os arquivos do `package.json` e do `package-lock.json`. No caso de um repositório público ou  compartilhado com outros, é uma boa prática criar um arquivo chamado `readme.md` com uma seção que ensina a instalar as dependências e a rodar o projeto.

Então, não se preocupe, quando alguém for baixar seu projeto, ela irá rodar o `npm install` e o projeto funcionará perfeitamente.

Comment: Muito bom, Fábio, Obrigado! Estava com essa dúvida, mas a explicação ajudou bastante.